# How to make a reset button appear after certain requirements?

Tags: javascript

So, i want a reset button to appear on my page when the score of the player reaches 5. But i can't seem to make it appear.

```
if (Score == 5) {
    btnQuestion.disabled = true;
    txtQuestionFeedback.innerText = "Correct! \n Congratulations, you've got 5 stars!";
    imgScore5.src = "Images/StarOn.gif";
    document.getElementById(btnReset).innerHTML = btnReset;
}
```

Comment: What is `btnReset` in this context?

Comment: In what way does this fail?  What is `btnReset`?  If it's an element, are you looking for the `.appendChild()` function?

Comment: do you have the listener? send more code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've sorted it guys!

Instead, i just used a visibility attribute on the button to hide it on page startup. And then called on that attribute in a Function for HideButton().

````
```
  function ShowResetButton() {
        document.getElementById("btnReset").style.visibility = "visible";
    }

```
````

But thank you all for your input! i really appreciate it!

Take it easy,

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1) Insert your button element inside a DIV like this for easier reading

```html
<div id="resetButtonDiv">
<button id="resetButton"></button> <!-- here goes your button config -->
</div>
```

2) Change the style like this using JS

```js
<script>

function showResetButton() {
 document.getElementById("resetButton").style.display = "none";   
 if (Score == 5) {
   // Replace "Score" with your variable or element
   document.getElementById("resetButton").style.display = "show";
 }
}
showResetButton()
</script>
```

Comment: There is no such value (`show`) for `style.display`.

Comment: I apologize, you need to define a CSS class. Allow me a moment to write it for you.

Comment: Try adding this inside the website's CSS
```css
#resetButton.show {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was my way to do it:

```js
ScoreBoard = function(sId, sIntoNode = '', fnOnChange = null) {
  this.m_sId = sId != '' ? sId : 'scoreboard';
  this.m_iScore = 0;
  this.m_fnOnChange = fnOnChange;
  
  if(sIntoNode != '') {
    let TargetNode = document.getElementById(sIntoNode);
    if(TargetNode) {
      TargetNode.innerHTML = TargetNode.innerHTML + '<div class="scoreboard-score" id="' + this.m_sId + '">0</div>';
    }
  }
}

ScoreBoard.prototype.SetScore = function(iNewScore) {
  this.m_iScore = iNewScore;
   
  let scoreBoard = document.getElementById(this.m_sId);
  if(scoreBoard) {
    scoreBoard.innerHTML = this.m_iScore;
  }
   
   
  if(this.m_fnOnChange && typeof this.m_fnOnChange == 'function') {
    this.m_fnOnChange(this);
  }
}

ScoreBoard.prototype.AddScore = function(iAmount) {
  this.SetScore(this.m_iScore + iAmount);
}

ScoreBoard.prototype.Reset = function() {
  this.SetScore(0);
}

ScoreBoard.prototype.GetScore = function() {
  return this.m_iScore;
}

function OnScoreChange(target) {
  let resetBtn = document.getElementById('myScore-reset');
  if(resetBtn) {
    if(target.GetScore() >= 5) {
      resetBtn.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      resetBtn.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

var myScore = new ScoreBoard('myScore', 'score', OnScoreChange);

var i = 0;
function test() {
  myScore.AddScore(1);
  i++;
  if(i < 20) setTimeout(test, 1000);
}

test();
```

```css
div#score {
  padding: 12px;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  font-family: Arial;
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 12px 3px black;
}

div.score-head {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 6px;
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
}

div.scoreboard-score {
  background-color: #EAEAEA;
  padding: 6px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}

div#score button {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="score">
  <button onClick="myScore.Reset();" id="myScore-reset">Reset Score</button>
  <div class="score-head">Score:</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Jose Barranco forgive me, i've been doing a course for a couple weeks and i'm still reeeaaalllyy new to all this.

I tried doing what you've said, And it makes the button invisible, which is great.. but it seems the "show" part of it doesn't, even if i make it a seperate function, and pout it directly into the if statement, and make it call the function.

any ideas?